# Using a session.storage variables in a link

Tags: html, storage

I'm trying to make a simple configurator using `session.storage` where the user first chose the first attribute, which then will be stored in a session.storage variable (ie: `onclick="sessionStorage.at1='red'"`)
then, then second and the third.

That works fine and I can display the different attributes as text - but I would like to show the corresponding image that I have made with the following syntax: `at1at2at3.jpg` (`redlargewood.jpg`) but I have no clue in how to actually use the variables like: `<img src=sessionStorage.at1 + sessionStorage.at2 + sessionStorage.at3 + ".jpg " >`

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this via javascript.Add id to your image tag and do the following in javascript:

```js
let first = 'red';
let second = 'large';
let third = 'wood';

let pic = `${first}${second}${third}.jpg`
document.getElementById('demo').src = pic;
```

Comment: Thanks - that pointed me in the correct direction :)